# Cloudfront denying CORS from one domain, but not the other

Tags: ajax, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Heroku app making AJAX requests to my cloudfront distribution via JQuery. When I load my website from myapp.herokuapp.com, everything works perfectly.

When I access the app from my custom domain (which is something like myapp.subdomain.domain.com), I get this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [cloudfront dist here]/something.json. Origin http://myapp.subdomain.domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

It's pretty weird. In my S3 CORS config, I'm allowing all domains with a `*`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Why would this happen? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably getting bitten by this S3/CloudFront bug https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=377513

when S3 sees request come in from myapp.herokuapp.com, it rewrites `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: myapp.herokuapp.com`, not the `*` you expect it to. And the CF caches that. So secondary requests from different domains will fail CORS validation, even when using the same CF distribution.